# Firebase Database sort by time of unknown node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve the following in time order:

[image: Firebase Database Structure]

Where the **known value** is the current token of the authenticated user but the **unknown value** is a user that has been created before, from a server environment.

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

    mDatabase.child("users").child(user.getUid());

    mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, Object>>() {
            };
            Map<String, Object> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

            assert map != null;


            for (Object e : map.values()) {
                list.add(e.toString());
            }

            for (Object e : map.keySet()) {
                list1.add(e.toString());
            }
```

I have tried to use orderByChild("time") on the addValueEventListener but I do not think its working as I can not point the right location in the database as I am unable to get the value of the user

**Edit:**

```
            try {
                for (int i = list1.size()-1; i == list1.size()-1; i++) {

                    String guestname = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(list1.get(i)).child("username").getValue());
                    String guestemail = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(list1.get(i)).child("email").getValue());
                    String guestpassword = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(list1.get(i)).child("password").getValue());

                    Log.w(TAG, "Name of newest value is " + guestname);
                    Log.w(TAG, "Email of newest value is " + guestemail);
                    Log.w(TAG, "Password of newest value is " + guestpassword);
                    guestname1 = guestname;
                    guestpassword1 = guestpassword;
                    guestemail1 = guestemail;
                }
```

Comment: Answer below. But since you're calling `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` it seems like you're on a very old version of the Firebase SDK. Consider [upgrading](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#update_your_database_code) to get the last two years worth of improvements that were made.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that, yeah not sure why that was in there but think I am already using the latest version.. In my gradle: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `orderByChild()` for that:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

Query query = mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).orderByChild("time")

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (dataSnapshot childNode: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      System.out.printl(childNode.getKey()); //this is the unknown key you marked
      System.out.printl(childNode.child("time").getValue(Long.class));
    }
  }

  ...
```

Comment: +1 Thanks looks right, I have never seen the childNode.key in any docs and I am getting an error in Android Studio when using this.. Cannot resolve symbol 'key'? Any idea

Comment: Woops... sorry about that. That should've been `getKey()` on Android. I've been doing too much JavaScript recently.

Comment: One last thing, could you check my edited answer to see how I was creating a hashmap before, I really want put all of the nodes in a hashmap sorted by time instead of just the values for time. I edited question to show the code... thanks

Comment: Most important is to use the loop I have over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`. Your code does `Map<String, Object> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(t)`, which loses the ordering information (since there's no space for it in a map).

Comment: Thanks, if I lose the ordering in a hashmap what is best to use, If I want to retrieve all the values in the unknown node which is sorted by time?

Comment: The to use is an ordered collection, like a `List`, and then convert from the (ordered) snapshot to that with the code I showed.